# Parse Robot Framework's output xml

Tags: python, robotframework

Robot framework spits out an output XML which is then used to build the HTML reports (with `rebot`), re-run failures, etc.

I need to parse this file to generate other reports, in particular, I need to parse the test case's documentation for a regex, get the test case result and then build a report (this is for integration with a legacy system).

Does Robot Framework provide functionality to easily parse the output XML file or we just use standard XML parsing libraries?

Comment: Robot framework does provide functionality to parse the output XML - for the purposes you listed, build the HTML reports, re-run failures, etc. You sound like you need custom data out of it - and there are not a lot of tools that will provide "any custom output out of xml", but programming.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/robotframework/DbBot

Comment: @LubosJerabek that seems cool and good for what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found 3 viable responses:

1. Use `DbBot` and query the DB created.
2. Parse the XML file directly. Using `xml.etree.ElementTree` is pretty simple.
3. Use Robot Framework's [ExecutionResult](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/robot/result/resultbuilder.html), which follows the *Visitor* pattern (in [ResultVisitor](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/robot/result/visitor.html), which we have to extend) and that allows you to do what you need in the `visit_test` method.

Ended up with going with option 3 as that is part of Robot Framework and less likely to break (or easier to fix) if the format of the XML file changes.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you extended the `visit_test` method (which I don't see in the ResultVisitor code)?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem as yours and for me using the Robot Framework's [Listener Interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) was the most convenient solution.

The `output_file` method from the [Listener version 3 API](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-3) will be invoked when writing to an output file is ready. The argument of the method is the absolute path to the output XML file, and that is all needed to create any kind of new reports.

Example:

```
import os

"""Listener that parses the output XML when it is ready and creates a unique log."""

ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

def output_file(path):
    # parse xml with etree or lxml
    log_dir = os.path.split(path)[0]
    print('Extra log: %s' % (log_dir + '\\extra.log'))
```

Console log of a test execution:

```
D:\robot_framework>robot --listener my_listener.py my_test.robot
==============================================================================
My Test
==============================================================================
Some Test                                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My Test                                                               | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Extra log: D:\robot_framework\extra.log
Output:  D:\robot_framework\output.xml
Log:     D:\robot_framework\log.html
Report:  D:\robot_framework\report.html
```

The additional log file is listed among the default outputs.

Answer (score 2):

This answer borrows from Bence's example, but adds functionality of echoing grand total summary lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# invoke with robot --listener API-Libs/RF_Listener.py

import xml.etree.ElementTree as xmlElementTree

ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

class RF_Listener:  # class should be same as filename

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

    def output_file(self, path):  # Listener that parses the output XML when it is ready
      root = xmlElementTree.parse(path).getroot()
      for type_tag in root.findall('./statistics/total/stat'):
      # <stat pass="1" fail="2">Critical Tests</stat>
      # <stat pass="3" fail="4">All Tests</stat>
        cntPassed = int(type_tag.attrib.get("pass"))  # attrib is dict-like (except for 'text')
        cntFailed = int(type_tag.attrib.get("fail"))
        cntTests = cntPassed + cntFailed
        pct_pass = cntPassed / cntTests * 100
        fmt_str = "{}: {} tests, {} passed, {} failed, {:.3g}% pass rate (--listener summary)"
        print(fmt_str.format(type_tag.text,cntTests, cntPassed, cntFailed,pct_pass))
      # optionally write grand total results summary to a file
```

This version prints to STDOUT instead of writing to a file, thus inserting these two lines near the end of the output. Suitable for `grep` (esp. for use in Jenkins job `description-setter` plugin.)

```
Critical Tests: 3 tests, 1 passed, 2 failed, 33.3% pass rate (--listener summary)
All Tests: 7 tests, 3 passed, 4 failed, 42.9% pass rate (--listener summary)
```

Comment: Robot Framework API provides a ResultVisitor that can be used to parse the XML. It is the same API that is used when creating the log.html by the framework itself.