# Grand total Robot Framework results reporting by Jenkins (all suites)

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

What is the best way to scrape a Robot Framework log for grand total of all results in a multi-suite scenario? My console log shows multiple lines like these:

```
6 critical tests, 5 passed, 1 failed
7 tests total, 5 passed, 2 failed
...
11 critical tests, 10 passed, 1 failed
13 tests total, 10 passed, 3 failed
```

But it is very frustrating there is no grand totals.
Seems like there should be a simple option to display this info, without writing custom code.

Answer (score 2):

The generated xml file has grand totals toward the end, inside the tag `<statistics>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot generator="Robot 3.1.2 (Python 3.7.2 on darwin)" generated="20190821 09:19:40.217" rpa="false">
  <suite id="s1" name="Hello" source="/private/tmp/hello.robot">
     ...
  </suite>
  <statistics>
    <total>
      <stat pass="1" fail="0">Critical Tests</stat>
      <stat pass="1" fail="0">All Tests</stat>
    </total>
    <tag>
    </tag>
    <suite>
      <stat pass="1" fail="0" id="s1" name="Hello">Hello</stat>
    </suite>
  </statistics>
  <errors>
  </errors>
</robot>
```

Comment: Ok, shouldn't be too hard to cook up a small python script to extract that info. Do you think it should be invoked as a listener? Or just ran after robot?

Comment: This might be a good listener-base method to trigger parsing the `outout.xml` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152481/parse-robot-frameworks-output-xml