# Robot Framework logs - how to modify output.xml in teardown?

Tags: robotframework

I have a question about '[--removekeywords](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#removing-keywords)'. According to RF User Guide about log outputs: "Removing keywords is done after parsing the output file and generating an internal model based on it."
Do we have any way to make the same parsing on output.xml as well?
I need that the same functionality will be also in xml file.
I really need this and will be appreciated for any help)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Robot Framework's output xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152481/parse-robot-frameworks-output-xml). Basically what is described in the referred question allows you to modify the output XML at that point as well.

Comment: Good suggestion) But what I need actually is functionality like '--removekeywords PASSED' but not in log.html so in output.xml. Because this file is sent to some log server that parse this file and paint it in red some keywords like 'wait until keyword succeed', in spite it succeeded but one of child iterations was red(((

Comment: About the arguments you have mentioned "When used during execution, they only affect the log file, not the XML output file. With rebot they affect both logs and possibly generated new output XML files." call rebot from the listener so those arguments will take effect on the new output.xml file. Or just call rebot after the execution but before the logs are sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you for advice I will try your flow)))